# PDO selects row with id=6 with statement such as WHERE id=6ff

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL statement using PDO that pulls based on the id from $_GET. It works correctly if the $_GET equals a number and if that number does not exist, it gives the correct error. What happens is that when the $_GET is something like 6ff, it still pulls the data for id 6 and ignores the ff. I want it to display an error.

Does anyone know why it would do that?

```
$sql = "SELECT players.*, users.*
  FROM players JOIN users ON players.member_id=users.user_id
  WHERE players.player_id = :playerid";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(array(':playerid' => $playerID));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

if $playerID = 6, I get player 6.
if $playerID = 6gjopj, i still get player 6

Comment: Validate it before you do the query. Either MySQL or PDO is converting the player ID to an integer.

Comment: The column type is INT and so MySQL is treating it as an int by truncation.

Comment: Have you tried MySQL strict mode on

Comment: `if((int)$playerID != $playerID) { echo "ERROR"; }`

Comment: Thank you.  These all make sense and I didn't even think about an of them.  Fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

The intiger validation should be done before you pass the value for query.

Happy coding